# UICollectionview cell selection

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

i have made a grid of images and in order to show its selection i drew border for the image when selected. but the problem is when i select some image at the top and scroll down the grid of images, some other image at the bottom also seemed to be selected. below is my code snippet:

```
UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"collectionCell" bundle:nil];
[self.collectionView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellCV"];

UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(95, 95)];
[flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];

[self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
```

Above has been added in viewDidLoad with the collection view cell designed in nib.

and implemented following delegates:

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
selectedImageIndex = indexPath.row;
[collectionView reloadData]; 
}

-(CollectionCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UIImage *img = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellCV";
CollectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:   
cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.imageView.image = img;
cell.imageView.tag = indexPath.row;
UIImageView *imgView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
if (indexPath.row == selectedImageIndex) {
    imgView.layer.borderWidth =  4.0;
    imgView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    NSLog(@"selected indexpath: %d", indexPath.row);
}
else {
    imgView.layer.borderWidth =  0.0;
    imgView.layer.borderColor = nil;
}
return cell;    
}
```

i could guess that something is going wrong with reusing the cell, but not sure and couldnt het an idea to resolve it.
Waiting for any kind of help and suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to use indexPath.item in place of indexPath.row. if you still face any problem then let me know

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Anurag, but still indexpath.item works in the same way as indexpath.row....

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I'm not seeing why this would take place. I do not believe the issue is the use of `row` vs `item`, though you really should use `item`. I can imagine, though, if your collection view has more than one `section`, that only looking at `row`/`item` but ignoring `section` would be a problem (i.e. it would select the same `item` number in *every* `section`).

To cut the Gordian knot, I'd suggest saving the `NSIndexPath` of the selected item, and then using that for the basis of comparison. That also makes it easy to render an optimization in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`. Anyway, first define your property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *selectedItemIndexPath;
```

And then implement `cellForItemAtIndexPath` and `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CollectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.imageView.image = ...

    if (self.selectedItemIndexPath != nil && [indexPath compare:self.selectedItemIndexPath] == NSOrderedSame) {
        cell.imageView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
        cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 4.0;
    } else {
        cell.imageView.layer.borderColor = nil;
        cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 0.0;
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // always reload the selected cell, so we will add the border to that cell

    NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];

    if (self.selectedItemIndexPath)
    {
        // if we had a previously selected cell

        if ([indexPath compare:self.selectedItemIndexPath] == NSOrderedSame)
        {
            // if it's the same as the one we just tapped on, then we're unselecting it

            self.selectedItemIndexPath = nil;
        }
        else
        {
            // if it's different, then add that old one to our list of cells to reload, and
            // save the currently selected indexPath

            [indexPaths addObject:self.selectedItemIndexPath];
            self.selectedItemIndexPath = indexPath;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // else, we didn't have previously selected cell, so we only need to save this indexPath for future reference

        self.selectedItemIndexPath = indexPath;
    }

    // and now only reload only the cells that need updating

    [collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
}
```

As an aside, note that I'm not messing around with the `tag` property (I see no value in that). Also note that rather than reloading entire collection view, I'm only reloading the selected cell (and if there was a previous selected cell, that one too), which should be more efficient.

Comment: Hi Rob, that worked out like anything.. And your solution gave a clear cut and cleared much of my confusions even in tableview stuff.. thanks a lot!! great!!!!!!

Comment: hi, when i select some other cell in the collection view, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath doesnt seem to get called. i am trying to do some work around in didDeselectItemAtIndexPath since the above code crashes when i double tap the cell to deselect it. i am sure that i have set the delegates properly. Any solution to avoid this crash or to invoke the 'deselect' delegate of collectionview friends?

Comment: @XiOS You can just change the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` to handle when you tap on the same item again. See revised answer.

Comment: Rob, is this the most dynamic way to handle selection on UICollectionView? what about when you select cell. remove manually from the rest of the cells the "selection"? or its a reuse problem as well?

Comment: I don't know if I'm wrong but the frameworks should do that work for me, but your solution works as I want, thank you !!! Rob.

Comment: If I need multiple selection ,then how could i do it efficiently

Comment: @SMS The easiest solution is to just (a) set `allowsMultipleSelection` and `allowsSelection` to `true`; (b) implement `didHighlightItemAtIndexPath` and `didUnhighlightItemAtIndexPath` to yield whatever visual effect you need. That's it. See [Managing the Visual State for Selections and Highlights](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCellsandViews/CreatingCellsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH7-SW8).

Comment: Hi @Rob how to reload items like this `[collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];` in swift3.

Comment: It's `collectionView?.reloadItems(at: indexPaths)`. Or, if `collectionView` isn't optional, remove the `?`.

Answer (score 1):

This code is in Swift 3:

```
if self.selectedItemIndexPath != nil && indexPath.compare(self.selectedItemIndexPath) == .orderedSame {
    cell.imageView!.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    cell.imageView!.layer.borderWidth = 4.0
} else {
    cell.imageView!.layer.borderColor = nil
    cell.imageView!.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
}

return cell
```